# DMZ forwarding on Cisco DPC/EPC2100 Cable Modem to Linksys Router for IP Cameras

Tags: port-forwarding, cable-modem, ip-camera, dmz

I have one of the old Cisco DPC/EPC2100 Cable Modems and wanted to know if anyone has had any luck setting up DMZ on it?

Link to modem: http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/modem_DPC2100.html

The modem's settings doesn't allow any config; all you can do is look at statuses eg. Signal strength, IP address, Up/Downstream frequency.

I need to DMZ the cable modem to a Linksys Router to get an IP camera to work. The IP Camera is connected to the Linksys Router.

Essentially, this is what I want to do.
 [Cable Modem] --DMZ--> [Linksys Router] --> [IP Cameras 1 & 2 & 3]

If I can save on buying another cable modem that would be great. I love to know if anyone knows a backdoor to this cable modem.

Many thanks.
WD